# Ubuntu - messed up partition table

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, disk-usage, lvm

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server vm on a Xen server.
I have 40Gb disk space allocated to it and my partition table looks like this

```
df -h
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                      16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                    3.1G  712K  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-root  8.3G  7.1G  797M  91% /
none                                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                      16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none                                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvda1                               236M   68M  156M  31% /boot
```

if you take a closer looks, you can see that my root partition has about 8gb allocated to it and is almost full. /run/shm has 16gb and /dev has another 16gb which are barely used.

I tried looking on google to findout if I can fix this issue but every solution I find suggests booting up using live cd and using gparted to manage the partitions. But being on a vm on Xen, I can't do that.

Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Thanks,
Kiran

**Edit**

output of `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-root: 9135MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  9135MB  9135MB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-swap_1: 33.6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  33.6GB  33.6GB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2
 2      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  extended
 5      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  logical                lvm
```

**Edit2**

I did some research on lvm and learned that I can resize the logical partitions using `lvextend` and `lvreduce`.

here is the output of `lvdisplay`

```
lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/QAAutomationServer-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                QAAutomationServer-vg
  LV UUID                ZRnyaa-fDlK-ulAH-2rcv-Haga-lxuU-TB0kqb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time QAAutomationServer, 2015-09-04 11:57:16 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.51 GiB
  Current LE             2178
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/QAAutomationServer-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                QAAutomationServer-vg
  LV UUID                QTPf2n-y8CA-FZDL-3xLH-33BX-mZIv-Zx1Jyu
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time QAAutomationServer, 2015-09-04 11:57:17 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                31.25 GiB
  Current LE             8000
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

So I am trying `lvreduce -L -5g /xyz` on the swap aprtition and then `lvextend -L +5g /abc` on the root partition.

and once that is done, I am doing a `sudo resize2fs /def` on the root partition

I am not sure this will ensure no loss of data but I can see that I have additional space on the root partition now.

```
df -h
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                      16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                    3.1G  712K  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-root   14G  7.1G  5.6G  57% /
none                                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                      16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none                                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvda1                               236M   68M  156M  31% /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown at the top of your note is not your partition table. It's a list of your mounted systems.
/run/shm and /dev are not 'real' filesystems. That are virtual filesystems located in the RAM of your computer. They do not use any of your disk space.
What is really interesting is:

```
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 42.9GB
[...]
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2
 2      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  extended
 5      257MB   42.9GB  42.7GB  logical                lvm
```

Your virtual disk device (~42GB of size) is divided on two primary partitions:
1: boot (mounted ad /boot)
2. extended
In your extended partition you have one partition for lvm. LVM stands for Linux Volume Manager. It creates a virtual block device, which you can use as regular block device, but extend or shrink 'on the fly', and build it with several physical volumes, which is very handy in some situations.

On that virtual device you have two virtual partitions:
First:

```
/dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-root: 9135MB
```

which is mounted as your root partition, and second:

```
/dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-swap_1: 33.6GB
```

which is your swap.

As you can see swap consumes over 3/4 of your whole drive.

So my advice is:
1. Turn off swap
2. Delete/shrink swap partition
3. Expand root partition
4. Resize rootfs (this can be done probably on 'live' filesystem)
5. Create swap partition using remaining space
6. Turn on swap

Here you'll find how to deal with LVM volumes: http://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Comment: I was able to extend the my logical volume and resize the root partition by using `lvextend` as described in my Edit2. Thanks for the link. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did my initial setup using `lvm`, I was able to use lvm to resize my logical volumes and then resize the root partition.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

`lvdisplay` - lists all lvm partitions available

`lvreduce -L -5g /lvmpartition` - reduces the selected lvmpartition by 5G

`lvextend -L +5g /lvmpartition` - extends the selected lvmpartition by 5G

Since I had about 30G allocated to swap, I was able to shrink it to 10G and extend the lvm-root partition with the resulting 20G free space.

Here is the output of `lvdisplay` after the modifications

```
  LV Path                /dev/QAAutomationServer-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                QAAutomationServer-vg
  LV UUID                ZRnyaa-fDlK-ulAH-2rcv-Haga-lxuU-TB0kqb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time QAAutomationServer, 2015-09-04 11:57:16 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                30.51 GiB
  Current LE             7810
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/QAAutomationServer-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                QAAutomationServer-vg
  LV UUID                QTPf2n-y8CA-FZDL-3xLH-33BX-mZIv-Zx1Jyu
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time QAAutomationServer, 2015-09-04 11:57:17 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                9.25 GiB
  Current LE             2368
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

now I did `sudo resize2fs` on the root partition and here is the output of `df -h`

```
df -h
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                      16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                    3.1G  712K  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/QAAutomationServer--vg-root   30G  7.1G   22G  25% /
none                                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                      16G  4.0K   16G   1% /run/shm
none                                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvda1                               236M   68M  156M  31% /boot
```

This boosted the space on my root partition. Hope this answer helps someone with similar problems.